# Route not defined exception in Laravel but Route is defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to call a route by pressing a button but it gives me
Route [makeAdmin] not defined. (View: \resources\views\admin\showUser.blade.php) even though the route is defined.

my blade view:

```
 <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
    @if($user->isAdmin == 0)
      <form action="{{route('makeAdmin', $user->id)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
         <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Make Admin</button>
         </div> 
     </form>
    @else
      <button class="btn btn-warning" disabled="disabled">Already Admin</button>
    @endif
  </div>
```

my routes:

```
Route::GET('/', 'CoursesController@root')->name('root');
Route::GET('/courses/create', 'CoursesController@create')->name('courses.create');
Route::POST('/courses', 'CoursesController@store')->name('courses.store');
Route::GET('/courses', 'CoursesController@index')->name('courses.courses');
Route::GET('/courses/{id}', 'CoursesController@show')->name('courses.show');
Route::GET('/admin/courses', 'AdminController@getCourses')->name('admin.courses');
Route::GET('/admin/users', 'AdminController@getUsers')->name('admin.users');
Route::GET('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
Route::GET('/admin/courses/{id}', 'AdminController@showCourse')->name('admin.showCourse');
Route::PUT('/admin/courses/{course}', 'AdminController@editCourse')->name('admin.editCourse');
Route::DELETE('/admin/courses/{course}', 'AdminController@destroyCourse')->name('admin.destroyCourse');
Route::GET('/admin/users/{id}', 'AdminController@showUser')->name('admin.showUser');
Route::PUT('/admin/users/{user}', 'AdminController@makeAdmin')->name('makeAdmin');
Route::PUT('/admin/users/{user}', 'AdminController@editUser')->name('admin.editUser');
Route::DELETE('admin/users/{user}', 'AdminController@destroyUser')->name('admin.destroyUser');



Auth::routes();
Route::GET('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I've tried route:clear and route:cache but the problem still appears. And the route doesn't appear in route:list
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: That route is in there twice: `Route::PUT('/admin/users/{user}'...`

Comment: Thank you ! That was the issue, I removed the duplicate route and made making admin feature into the edit user form. Thank you again.

Comment: Not a problem, glad it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appeared to be that I have a duplicate route inside web.php

```
Route::PUT('/admin/users/{user}', 'AdminController@makeAdmin')->name('makeAdmin');
Route::PUT('/admin/users/{user}', 'AdminController@editUser')->name('admin.editUser');
```

Appearently, this is not how things work in Laravel, so I removed the makeAdmin route and added the feature as a part of editUser form I have in my blade view. So web.php will only have this:

```
Route::PUT('/admin/users/{user}', 'AdminController@editUser')->name('admin.editUser');
```

Thanks all for participating. And a special thanks to kerbholz.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly it looks like every `/admin` route in your `route.php` is named prefixied with `admin.`

So maybe try to name the route as `admin.makeAdmin` and call it in your view like so:

```
<form action="{{route('admin.makeAdmin', $user->id)}}" method="POST">
```

See if it works.

Comment: Yeah that was the oriignal code I just tried to edit the name so it might work. However, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<form action="{{route('makeAdmin',['user'=>$user->id])}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but the same exception keeps appearing.

Comment: @RedJohn I update my answer. And It works nice for me

Comment: It was a great idea to associate the value with array element but still doesn't work for me. However, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

In the route for makeAdmin just specify POST instead of PUT. Because in form HTML you have mentioned that method

Comment: If you use put in route, you must be use put in form. If problem was put or post, laravel get error, method not allowed

Comment: Not really a good solution since I can specifiy inside blade form that I use put.